# Android: draw triangle on top of triangle

Tags: android, shapes

I am trying to draw something like this http://www.laviny.sk/themes/hzs/images/pocasie/r/r2.png using android XML shape. It is one big triangle (45° on bottom) and one smaller triangle on top of it.  I am planing on using it on image like this http://www.laviny.sk/themes/hzs/images/pocasie/r/r0.png. I know that I could use simple png image of this but I want to set its color programatically so thats why I am trying to use android shape.

Is this too complex to be drawn by shape? If not can you please try to guide me a bit because I really dont know how should I approach this problem.

Thanks in forward

Answer (score 0):

Layer-list should be able to do that. The other way is to extend ImageView and draw what you like on a canvas within the onDraw method.